# Azure DocumentDB - How can I fetch documents from the collection of particular date?

Tags: java, database, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

Each document contains date property shows when it is stored, so how can I fetch data stored on particular date or between two dates. What is the best way to do this. My implementation is based on Java. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the Java code, but you'll have to set up your collection to use Range indexing on the DateTime strings, then you'll be able to query for dates within a certain time range. The .NET code is to set up range indexing is:

```
DocumentCollection collection = new DocumentCollection { Id = "orders" };
collection.IndexingPolicy = new IndexingPolicy(new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 });
await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync("/dbs/orderdb", collection);
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-working-with-dates#indexing-datetimes-for-range-queries and search for Range on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-indexing-policies.

Answer (score 0):

Just using Azure DocumentDB SDK for Java to query documents by `_ts` property. The document `_ts` property is as below.

> **_ts**: This is a system generated property. It specifies the last updated timestamp of the resource. The value is a timestamp.

Here is my sample code as below. The `_ts` unit is second.

```
// Initialize a DocumentDb client.
String serviceEndpoint = "https://<your-documentdb-name>.documents.azure.com:443/";
String masterKey = "<your-documentdb-key>";
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(serviceEndpoint, masterKey, ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault(), ConsistencyLevel.Session);
// Get a collection link via collection id.
String collId = "<collection-Id>";
String query = String.format("SELECT * from ROOT r WHERE r.id = '%s'", dcId);
FeedOptions options = null;
List<DocumentCollection> dcs = client.queryCollections(dbLink, query, options).getQueryIterable().toList();
String collLink = dcs.size() >0 ? dcs.get(0).getSelfLink() : null;
// Generate a query string, see below.
.......
client.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), query, null);
```

A query string for fetching data stored on particular date:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String dateStr = "2017-03-01";
long timestamp = sdf.parse(dateStr).getTime()/1000;
String query = String.format("select * from c where c._ts = %d", timestamp);
```

A query string for fetching data stored between two dates:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String startDateStr = "2017-03-01";
String endDateStr = "2017-03-31";
long tsStart = sdf.parse(startDateStr).getTime()/1000;
long tsEnd = sdf.parse(endDateStr).getTime()/1000;
String query = String.format("select * from c where c._ts >= %d and c._ts <= %d", tsStart, tsEnd);
```